# Quality Attribute Trade-off in Eclipse Architecture

Tags: eclipse

I'm currently working on a project that is concerned with the software architecture of the Eclipse IDE.
My aim is to make a trade-off analysis between two key quality attributes, in this case Modifiability and Performance. The plug-in architecture in Eclipse is obviously promoting a high degree of modifiability, but my research is currently concerned with whether this level of modifiability is impacting performance in running Eclipse (performance-weaknesses in the Eclipse architecture). I've been trying to find some reliable info on this for quite some time, but have so far found very little.

If anyone has some pointers/tips on this subject, it will be much appreciated!

Comment: You're going to have to define performance.  Do you mean processing speed, memory footprint, or some combination?  You might try reading notes in the Eclipse Bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: With performance I mean a combination of hardware resources. Is there, for example, known issues in Eclipse when it comes to loading and using too many plug-ins at the same time. Of course this is all very generic, but the essence of my question is; is there any known architectural trade-offs in Eclipse between modifiability and performance?

Comment: I'm not a member of the Eclipse foundation, so all I could give you are opinions based on working with Eclipse 3 and Eclipse 4.  My short opinion is that the modularity of Eclipse is not as useful as one might think.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Eclipse's plugin architecture is specifically designed to take memory footprint and general performance into consideration. For example, plugins are lazy-loaded, meaning Equinox will wait until the functionality is actually invoked/requested before loading a plugin. This even goes as far as enabling the discovery and/or representation of a plugin's functionality in the UI without having to actually load and activate that plugin. These were conscious and direct design decisions made with performance in mind.

See *[When Does a Plug-in Get Started?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_When_does_a_plug-in_get_started?)*

[Here is another example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Boot_Delegation) of a design change that was made that both improved performance and provided a cleaner design.